# Is there anything like Interclue for chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

When I used Firefox I was a huge fan of [Interclue](http://interclue.com/). I've switched to Chrome for the most part, but many times I find myself in a situation where something like Interclue would be extremely handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ezLinkPreview](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnkcfbiefgdaceeplickkkmifpicbpcc) looks pretty similar. There's a nice, basic overview at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15395/preview-links-and-images-in-google-chrome/).

Comment: It is pretty similar. It's not quite the same (Interclue made very efficient use of bandwidth by loading just the text in many situations), but I'll take it. Thanks a ton. :)